# Why is my ajax form submission goal not being tracked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

I'm trying to submit a goal event after valid ajax form submission.

I'm using analytics.js and I've created the goal, but this is my first attempt at goals so I may be missing something crucial.
The form validates and submits correctly, it's just not tracking the goals in google analytics.

My entire form function is below, but the problem area must be:

```
// custom event for google analyics
$(document).on('formSuccess', function() {
    ga('send','event','form','submission');
})
```

My goal, as it's setup in GA is:

```
Category:'form'    
Action: 'submission'    
Label: blank    
Value: blank
Use the Event value as the Goal Value for the conversion: Yes
```

When I verify, I get a 0% conversion. Is it even possible to verify an ajax form?

I have an eventListener for 'formSuccess' early on and I'm triggering the event in ajax.success if response.success is true. Everything else is working just fine, btw.

---

```
REA.mailForm = function() {
    var formId = '#tour-form';

    // custom event for google analyics
    $(document).on('formSuccess', function() {
        ga('send','event','form','submission');
    })

    $(formId).submit(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        var firstName = $(formId+' #first-name').val();
        var lastName = $(formId+' #last-name').val();
        var phone = $(formId+' #phone').val();
        var email = $(formId+' #email').val();
        var datePicker = $(formId+' #date-picker').val();
        var timePicker = $(formId+' #time-picker').val();
        var referral = $(formId+' #referral option:selected' ).val();
        var formData = {};
        var alertElement = $(formId+' .alert');

        alertElement.removeClass('alert-success alert-danger');

        var alertClass = '';
        var alertText = '';
        var showAlert = function(alertClass, alertText) {
            alertElement
            .addClass(alertClass)
            .show()
            .find('.alert-text').text(alertText);

        };

        // super basic validation
        // if((firstName && lastName && phone && email) !== '') {
            // prepare each form field for php form processing
            formData.firstName = firstName;
            formData.lastName = lastName;
            formData.phone = phone;
            formData.email = email;
            formData.datePicker = datePicker;
            formData.timePicker = timePicker;
            formData.referral = referral;
            formData.website = window.location.pathname;

            // send data and examine response
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'process.php',
                data: formData,
                success: function(data) {
                    var response = JSON.parse(data);
                    if(response.failure){
                        alertClass = 'alert-danger';

                        for (var key in response) {
                            alertText += response[key]+'\n';
                        }

                    } else if(response.success) {
                        alertClass = 'alert-success';
                        alertText = response.success;
                        REA.clearForm(formId);
                        // custom event for analytics
                        $(document).trigger('formSuccess');
                    }

                    showAlert(alertClass, alertText);
                },
                error: function() {
                    showAlert('alert-danger', 'Sorry. Something went wrong. Your message was not received.');
                }
            });

            var timer = setTimeout(function() {
                clearTimeout(timer);
                alertElement
                .removeClass('alert-success alert-danger')
                .hide()
                .find('.alert-text').text('');
            }, 10000);

            return false;
        // }
    });
}
```

Comment: your GA part looks fine. I suggest checking the console that your formSuccess method is actually reachable.

Comment: @Jacob, it's reachable. I was successfully running a console log from it. So maybe my issue is between the ga() and google analytics. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out it just need about 24 hours to gather data and populate it into analytics. There was never anything wrong at all.